# Make Angularjs re-attach a DOM node instead of updating it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my template I currently have something like this:

```
<div>
    <a ng-href="tel:{{phone}}">{{ phone }}</a>
</div>
```

When `$scope.phone` changes angular will update the link's DOM node to make it link to the new phone number. This works fine.

However there is a commonly used third party browser plugin that replaces the phone number within the `<a>` tag with a formatted phone number + icon. Unfortunately when the `$scope.phone` variable changes angularjs updates the DOM node but the browser plugin doesn't detect this and keeps showing the old phone number.

To solve this I was thinking on re-attaching the entire div or link to the page whenever the phone property changed. Is here anything in angularjs that allows me to do this easily (ie. re-attach a dom node instead of updating it?).

The solution I have right now is to temporarily set a property $scope.reattach to true and after 0 miliseconds set it to false again. Then check that property in an ng-if. But this feels so dirty.

Comment: Sounds as if you want to degrade your application to overcome a deficiency in the browser plug-in. Is that the right way to read this?

Comment: Whatever you do will likely be dirty

Comment: I guess so. The plugin is used a lot in my country even by big companies (the replacing of the phone numbers is just a small feature its not the main function of the plugin). Our clients are complaining that the data that we show is incorrect and they can often not turn the plugin off because they use it for their internal voicecalls.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is a bit dirty but reliable. I would use ng-repeat with an array of one phone. Then I would `push()` the new phone and `shift()` the array to remove the first one.

HTML :

```
<div>
    <a ng-repeat="phone in phones track by phone" 
       ng-href="tel:{{phone}}">{{ phone }}</a> 
       <!-- Track by phone cause the new phone will have the same index as the old one like mentionned by skyboyer in the comment -->
</div>
```

JS :

```
$scope.phones = [];
$scope.changePhone = function(phone) {
    $scope.phones.push(phone); // Add the new phone to the end of the array.
    $scope.phones.shift(); // Remove the old phone at the beginning.

};
```

Comment: Or maybe `track by $index`

Comment: in your example `changePhone` will result in phone having the same index(`0`) upon dirty check cycle.